# Comparing different columns in a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I look through lots of data, sometimes with up to 1000 rows. For each of those 1000 rows, I look for specific errors. For example, column D may contain the "Employee Designation" and Column F may contain the "Pay Plan." If the "Employee Designation" is "Contractor" in column D, then Column F for that Row (Pay Plan) should contain the text, "Hourly Compensation."

However, if the "Employee Designation" is "Government" in column D, then Column F for that Row (Pay Plan) should contain the text, "Salary." I often find that sometimes column F does not contain the appropriate pay plan for the employee designation.

How can I make a query or conditional formatting that shows when Column F does not have the appropriate value based on the text in column D?

I have not tried anything because I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Add some sample rows (formatted text) to show what you have and the desired output. Also, how many combinations do you have?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming row 1 is headers, and this formula is being written in column F

If you want to add more conditions to validate

`=ifs(D2="Contractor","Hourly Compensation",D2="Government","Salary")`

If it's just these two options and one or the other

`=if(D2="Contractor","Hourly Compensation","Salary")`

However, I would recommend you make a table of all the different Employee Designations by copying the entire column, pasting as values, then removing duplicates. This will identify if you have some trailing spaces or anything odd in your dataset. Then label them accordingly and do a lookup to bring in those values. (the below formula assumes you have two columns, the designation & the label)

`=vlookup(D2, [Your table], 2,0)`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to correct them but rather just highlight them, then you can use a `conditional format` rule that uses a vlookup against a look-up reference.

Let's pretend columns I and J are your "correct" allocations for employee_type and plan. Best to have these in another sheet, btw.

Select your Column F data and input this conditional format rule and set your fill:

```
=(VLOOKUP(D2,I:J,2,FALSE)<>F2)
```

The rule is boolean and will highlight the column F cell when the pay type does not match your reference for that type of employee.

[image]